# How to make csv appear as numbers instead of E(python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

The csv created using `dataframe.to_csv()` contains `1.6135E+14` instead of `161349731180627`. In the dataframe, it was confirmed that `161349731180627` is displayed correctly. How do I get `161349734480627` in csv properly? (in python)

Comment: What's the dtype of the column that contains these numbers

Comment: I tried with int and objects but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `df.to_csv()`, add the argument `float_format='{:f}'.format`

Comment: Also try with `%.nf` where n is the precision number

Comment: I tried but failed. It seems that the value of the dataframe should be fixed, but I don't know how.

Comment: I found it to be an excel problem. Thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

To change the format of the output of to_csv, just use the float_format argument.

```
df.to_csv('sample.csv', float_format='%.15f')
```

You can set float format to any standard format -- float_format="%.2f", for example, will show two decimal places.

Comment: I found it to be an excel problem. Thank you for answer